# Problem with SQL query

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g-r2

I have the following Problem: I want as output a specific document (TITLE) that contains two different terms (TERM). For example the title of a fairy tale, that contains the names of two different characters. And I have the following data structure (**bold=tables**, *italic=keys*):

**DOCUMENT** ( *DOCUMENT_ID*, TITLE )

**DOCUMENT TERM** ( *DOCUMENT ID*->DOCUMENT, *POSITION OF TOKEN IN DOCUMENT*, TERM,
TOKEN, POS ID->POS )

**POS** ( *POS ID*, LOW, HIGH, DESCRIPTION, LONG DESCRIPTION, PARENT POS->POS )

I tried the following solution, but it didn't work. I hope someone can help:

```
SELECT
    TITLE
FROM
    DOCUMENT
WHERE 
    DOCUMENT_ID
IN (
    SELECT
        DOCUMENT_ID
    FROM
        DOCUMENT_TERM
    WHERE
        (TERM = 'Term1') AND (TERM = 'Term2')
)
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted**](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Oracle version: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production With the Partitioning, OLAP and Data Mining options through PHP extension oci8  is the database iam using

Comment: How can a document term be "Term1" **and** "Term2" at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A field can never have 2 different values. Try the `INTERSECT`:

```
SELECT TITLE
FROM   DOCUMENT
WHERE  DOCUMENT_ID IN
 (SELECT DOCUMENT_ID FROM DOCUMENT_TERM WHERE TERM = 'Term1'
  INTERSECT
  SELECT DOCUMENT_ID FROM DOCUMENT_TERM WHERE TERM = 'Term2');
```

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for. Thank your for your help, Sir!

Comment: This is also called using  'or' ....

Comment: @Beege: no it's not. An `OR` is something different

Comment: It's more like `AND` than like `OR`.

Comment: I sit corrected. It is more like 'and'. (No more answers before coffee.)